# Question about the experience of time while falling

Tags: general-relativity, gravity

If someone falls from a high altitude on planet Earth, does their experience of time increase or decrease? My understanding is that time will slow by a factor as their speed increases, but time will also speed up by a factor as the amount of gravity their experience increases. Which would be stronger?

Answer (score 1):

The speed with which an object falls through the earth's atmosphere is far too small to create any appreciable relativistic time dilation. Similarly, the difference in the strength of the earth's gravity from a point just above the earth's atmosphere and its surface is small enough that you would need a very accurate set of instruments to measure the effect it would have on how fast your clock ran.

However, even if you could reach relativistic velocities while falling to earth or even if you could fall deeply enough into the earth's gravitational potential well to slow your clock, you yourself would experience no shift in your perception of the rate of time's passage. To you, time would pass completely normally. Others watching you would see your clock slowing down, and to you, their clocks would seem to be running slow as well.

Comment: Great explanation for a newbie like me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The gravitational component of the time dilation relative to a far away observer is

$$\varsigma = 1/\sqrt{1-r_s/r}$$

and the kinematic component is the Lorentz factor

$$\gamma = 1/\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}$$

so in the frame of the infalling observer that cancels each other out when the velocity is the escape velocity

$$v=v_{\rm esc}= \pm c \ \sqrt{r_s/r}$$

since in the falling observer's frame whose proper time is $\tau$ the total time dilation is

$${\rm d}t/{\rm d}\tau=\varsigma / \gamma$$

In the frame of the far away observer with time $t$ the falling clock can only slow down:

$${\rm d}t/{\rm d}\tau= \varsigma \cdot \gamma$$

That is because the gravitational component is absolute, but the kinematic component is relative.